# Unexpected input from turbo c++ emulator using DOSBox

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main(){
    float a,b,c;
    clrscr();
    cout<<"enter a and b ";
    cin>>a>>b;
    c=a+b;
    cout<<a<<"+"<<b<<"="<<c;
    getch();
}
```

Upon running this:
[image: Screenshot of cmd session]

I did some digging with the debugger and the input is never received.

Why is this happening

Comment: Is there something about having to link with the floating point classes? Anyway, [throw that ancient complier away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961828/why-should-i-not-use-turbo-c)!

Comment: conio.h functions (implemented over BIOS) are not compatible with streams, hard to tell which consume input

Comment: @KenY-N I was forced to take up this ancient compiler and that too c++ programming only because to help a kid with his syllabus where in his school still  c++ is being taught in turbo c++ compiler.They are clinging on to borland's product what to do .

Comment: @JacekCz any fix .

Comment: when you did cin ..Did you enter any value for a and b ??if not those are the garbage value

Comment: I entered values @HariomSingh but they were not appearing in the console screen instead they the cursor was moving right after each key stroke.I entered 10 space 11 then I press enter.I used debugger they are only showing garbage values no idea why.Help me if you can

Comment: definitely the values are not getting entered ..same behavior I saw when the value was entered 'a' a char instead of a int

Comment: @HariomSingh yes exactly this simple program should run without any problem but its showing errors I don't know why the cin input is never assigned to the variable which is used to read them.I don't remember now there was some fix for it .I back c++ after 6-7 years so I don't remember it.But was hoping someone in SO community know about this garbage value problem and its fix

Comment: I have no longer a TC++ on my machine, but I would have never mixed conio and c++ streams on input! So remove that ugly `#include <conio.h>` and `getch()`, compile from TC++ and execute directly in a console window, or execute from TC through the debugger with a breakpoint on the `return 0;` from main.

Comment: Give correct output on the Turbo c++ 4.5

Comment: I often wonder why Indian universities ascribe value to using a compiler tool that hasn't been updated for decades and implements a language bearing minimal relationship to the modern C++ language. Honestly, you may as well teach people PL/1 or 6502 assembly language.

Comment: Which version of TC++, by the way?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there's something in the keyboard buffer that feeds garbage data to `cin`.

Try `while(kbhit()) getch();` before `cin>>a>>b;` and let me know if that helps.

Comment: OK I will check that and get back to you